# Create a Secure MYSQLI Login Script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working with MYSQL in the past and am no expert but have managed to produce a simple MySQL login script. However I am aware that my script is basic and outdated, and that I should be using MYSQLI,

However MYSQLI doesn't really make any sense to me as I have tried the following code in MySQL but I can't seem to get it to work and I get undefined index errors.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo 'MySQLi Connection was not established:';

}

// checking the user



$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST[‘myusername’]);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST[‘mypassword’]);

$sel_user = 'select * from supplier_users where username=’$myusername’ AND password=’$pass';

$run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION[‘user’]=$myusername;

echo “success”;

}

else {

echo “fail”;

}


?>
```

here is my MySQL login script which works fine:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
$tbl_name="internal_users";  
$tbl_name2="supplier_users";  
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql = "select * from $tbl_name where username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'
union
select * from $tbl_name2 where username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($count==1){
session_start();
include("variables.php");
if($result){
$sql2 = "UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET online = 'online' WHERE online = 'offline' AND username = '$myusername'";  
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); 
$sql21 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET online = 'online' WHERE online = 'offline' AND username = '$myusername'";  
$result21=mysql_query($sql21); }
else
$_SESSION['val']=1;
header("location:../dashboard.php");
}
else {
$_SESSION['message2'] = '<div id="message_box2"><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div><h23>Oooops!</h23><p>The Username and Password Combination do not match. Please try again.</p> </div>';
header("location:../index.php");
} 
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

my config.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="mark";
$password="password";
$db_name="hewden1";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Could Not Connect to Server");
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("Cannot Connect the Database"); 
?>
```

my question is, could someone please show me how I can convert my simple login script from MYSQL to MYSQLI and make it more secure in the way that I am trying to do above? I really would appreciate anyone's help with this as I am really struggling to understand.

Thanks

Comment: you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189) post for detailed explanation

Comment: Well done for defending against SQL injection, but you should certainly not store passwords in plain text. If your database leaks out, your users' security may be compromised elsewhere. In terms of using MySQLi, have you read the manual, or looked at examples? There are a lot on the web, including on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The Mysqli code that you posted seems sort of malformed, the quotes are some other encoding type quotes : ’ When it should be ' IDK if that would make sense though.
Also in your select statement :

```
$sel_user = 'select * from supplier_users where username=’$myusername’ AND password=’$pass';
```

in the end a quote is missing and it should rather be like

```
$sel_user = "select * from supplier_users where username='$myusername' AND password='$pass'";
```

and it doesn't make sense to use mysql() instead of mysqli(), since the former is depreciated .